# Using a dictionary to index parallel arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have 4 parallel arrays based on a table representing attributes of a map. Each array has approx. 500 values, but all have the same number of values.

The arrays are:

`start` = location of the endpoint with the smaller flow accumulation,

`end` = location of the other endpoint (with the larger flow accumulation),

`length` = segment length, and;

`shape` = actual shape, oriented to run from start to end.

I am attempting to create a data structure from which I can use a recursive function on to determine the start and end points every 2000m along the length.

The following question and answer describe what I am attempting to accomplish:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87649/select-points-approx-2000-metres-from-another-point-along-a-river

How do I store these 4 parallel arrays in a dictionary keyed by start?

I am new to writing functions, dictionaries and using arrays in dictionaries. I am attempting to do this task in Python.

Comment: Although it isn't necessarily required here, it may be useful to create a [class](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) that has start/end/length/shape attributes. That way, you could have a single list of `RiverSegment` objects (or whatever you want to call them) instead of four lists of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do things a little bit more *Python*-esque, you can use `enumerate`:

```
d = {}
for (i,st) in enumerate(start):
    d[st] = (shape[i],length[i],end[i])
```

or even better - `zip`:

```
d = {}
for (st,sh,le,en) in zip(start,shape,length,end):
    d[st] = (sh,le,en)
```

Note that you can leave out the parantheses around the first part of the `for` loops (i.e. between the `for` and `in` keywords). I used them solely for enhanced code readability.

As with [WeaselFox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22172958/1278792), `d[some_start_value]` will now hold the corresponding `shape`, `length` and `end` values.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you mean:

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(start)):
   d[start[i]] = (shape[i],length[i],end[i])
```

so now `d[some_start_value]` will hold the corresponding shape length and end values.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, I would recommend using `namedtuple` to simplify accesses:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# This creates a namedtuple called GISData. Name of the object and name in the first argument 
# should be the same. 
GISData = namedtuple('GISData', 'start shape length end')

# zip creates 1 list of 4-tuples from 4 single lists
# There are other ways to write this; this is just the shortest for me.
# Note that if you need this ordered, you should use an OrderedDict,
# which is in the collections module in python 2.7+, or you can find
# backported versions for python 2.6+. In those, the keys preserve ordering,
# so can still be searched as a list, which is useful if you need to find e.g.
# 479, which is not in the dictionary, but 400 and 500 are and you have to interpolate etc.

GISDict = dict((x[0], GISData(*x)) for x in zip(start, shape, length, end))

# The dictionary for any given start value
# Access the 4 individual pieces by name, or by index
GISDict[start_lookup].shape
```

etc.